# TinyCore with GRUB2 and secure boot out of the box

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot, tinycore

I’m trying to put manually GRUB instead of Windows boot loader (without chainloading) over a UEFI with secure boot enabled computer.

I tried to put `shimx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi` at the ESP alongside `grubx64.efi` in order to load TinyCore and I set through bcdedit the `{bootmgr}` path as `shimx64.efi`’s but it seems to fail (the UEFI panicking because of non signed binary).

I though I might be able to use GRUB as signed bootloader out of the box without the need to self-sign it (which will defeat the purpose of the project if I will need to self-sign it) but it seems I’m in the wrong.

Does anyone managed to run **TinyCore** specifically with GRUB under secure boot without self signing grub? Thanks